# Jquery: Handling click on a dynamically added row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding a row to the table using the following function:

```
function loadTable()
{
    var index, html, tbody;
    //clear the table

    for (index = 0; index < content.length; index++)
    {
        var tbody = document.getElementById("tablei").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        var row = document.createElement("TR");
        row.setAttribute("id", index);
        row.setAttribute("class", "selectableRow editableDiv");
        var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
        td1.innerHTML = content[index].Author;
        var td2 = document.createElement("TD");
        td2.innerHTML = content[index].AuthorType;
        var td3 = document.createElement("TD");
        td3.innerHTML = content[index].CosignStatus;
        var td4 = document.createElement("TD");
        td4.innerHTML = content[index].FileTime;
        var td5 = document.createElement("TD");
        td5.innerHTML = content[index].NoteTime;

        row.appendChild(td1);
        row.appendChild(td2);
        row.appendChild(td3);
        row.appendChild(td4);
        row.appendChild(td5);
        tbody.appendChild(row);
    }
}
```

I added a jquery function to catch the clicking event on the row.

```
$('.selectableRow').click(function (event)
{

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var item = content[parseInt(id)];
    alert(id);
}
```

But no alert shows up when the row is clicked.

But twhen I add the same code directly in html, the alert is called.

Comment: Is the `loadTable` function being called before the `click` function is set?

Comment: Is $('.selectableRow').click(function (event) in the document.ready section?

Comment: Click call no longer works for dynamically added html .... you can use .on or .live callbacks ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are adding a handler to things that don't yet exist.
Try wrapping your click handler inside a `change()` function:

```
$(document).change(function(){
    $('.selectableRow').click(function (event){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var item = content[parseInt(id)];
        alert(id);
    })
});
```

Even better, you could do:

```
$(document).on('click', '.selectableRow', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var item = content[parseInt(id)];
    alert(id);
});
```

From JQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> **Delegated** events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.

Comment: Note: Avoid using `body` for delegated events. If styling results in a zero-computed body height, then mouse events will not bubble to `body`. Use `document` as the default (as it also hints in that text you copied).

Answer (score 0):

Your approach not work because you are adding a listener only to the existing `tr`. You need to add the listener after of append the new `tr`

you can wrap the click event on a function to call just after append the element.

Just remember to unbind the event when you add the new one

```
$(element).unbind('click', function(){});
$(element).bind('click', function(){});
```

Here is a fiddle with a example

https://jsfiddle.net/mhr9coLs/1/